# jQuery .end method not working with jQuery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-end

I have a custom plugin very simple. If it returns `this` after calling it, `.end()` works great. However if it returns `$(this)`, `.end()` doesn't work. Why does that happen? Am I missing something here?

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/umbdj/3/):

```
$.fn.fnBar = function() {
    $(this).html("hello!");
    //return $(this); // Doesn't work
    return this; // Works!
};


$("div")
    .find("span")
        .fnBar()
    .end()
    .css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation :

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and
>   return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

In

```
$("div").find("span").fnBar().end()
```

`end` sets the state of the filtering to the one before the call to `find`.

With just `$(this)`, you're rebuilding a new jQuery object, without any history. You have no filtering operation and no chain, so it has nothing to cancel.

jQuery `end` function is implemented like this :

```
end: function() {
    return this.prevObject || this.constructor(null);
},
```

This means you can see the difference by logging the `prevObject` property of your jQuery object :

```
console.log(this.prevObject);
console.log($(this).prevObject); // will give undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside a jQuery method, `this` is already the jQuery object. `$(this)` creates a completely **new** jQuery object, with no filtering history.

Same problem, but maybe easier to understand:

```
var bar = $("div").find("span");
// This doesn't work
$(bar).end().css("color", "red");
// This does
bar.end().css("color", "red");
```